# Filter Class for Message Driven Bean's

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0

I have a requirement like below:

We have 20 Message Driven Beans in our application, when ever message has been arrived for each bean I need to log that information to database about the message. I can add this to each bean, but I need to change each and every class for each.

**Is there a way where we can add some Filter class which will be fired before execution of MDB onMessage method. So that, I can have one class for logging all the MDB messages**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should use some AOP technique. In detail, EJB provides an easy way to apply interceptors on MDBs:

```
public class LoggingInterceptor {
    ...
    @AroundInvoke
    protected Object myInterceptor(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        //do logging here...
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}

@Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)
public class SomeBean implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Example taken from [Configuring an Interceptor Class for an EJB 3.0 MDB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b28221/mdb30cfg010.htm).

To address your question from comment: you have access to [`InvocationContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html) inside an interceptor which exposes all required attributes:

```
String class = ctx.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName();
Message msg = (Message)ctx.getParameters()[0];
```

Note that you can even alter the parameter or use a different one in interceptor.

You tagged your message with [ejb-3.0](/questions/tagged/ejb-3.0) and [spring](/questions/tagged/spring). In [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/html/aop.html) options are much more flexible, but the general idea still applies.

Comment: Do i get the message being invoked in onMessage in this method also myInterceptor(..) ? And how can i identify which mdb has been invoked if i have 20 MDB's?

Comment: @Rana: see my update, this is perfectly possible using `InvocationContext`.